# Why does this stream return no element?

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, eclipselink, java-stream

I tried to write the following code as a stream:

```
AbstractDevice myDevice = null;

for (AbstractDevice device : session.getWorkplace().getDevices()) {

    if (device.getPluginconfig().getPluginType().getId() == 1) {
        myDevice =  device;
    }

}
```

this code works fine.

But when I rewrite it like this it doesn't work anymore:

```
myDevice = session.getWorkplace().getDevices().stream()
                  .filter(s -> s.getPluginconfig().getPluginType().getId() == 1)
                  .findFirst().get();
```

The `Optional` which I get back from the stream has no values in it. Why?

**EDIT**

When I try this (I still get two devices back from `getDevices()`):

```
 List<AbstractDevice> testList = session.getWorkplace().getDevices()
                                        .stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the `testList` is empty. So it seems like something goes wrong with the stream of my `List` of devices?

It's a JavaEE application and I get my Devices from the corresponding entity:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(name = "Workplace_AbstractDevice",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "Workplace", referencedColumnName = "ID")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "AbstractDevice", referencedColumnName = "ID")
            })
@OrderColumn
private List<AbstractDevice> devices = new ArrayList<AbstractDevice>();


public List<AbstractDevice> getDevices() {
    return devices;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? It's hard to diagnose without being able to reproduce it.

Comment: The original code would get the last matching item off the list, while the stream code would get the first. I don't know if that is the problem in this case.

Comment: "*The list i get back from session.getWorkplace.getDevices() has two objects in it*" are you sure about it? Also your non-stream solution seems to find last match not first one.

Comment: yes I debugged it and the list is the same as in the old code. I'm also aware of the first/last match issue but this doesn't really matter. There is no difference between the old  and new code right? (except the first/last match)

Comment: Can you try without the filter? Just to make sure it's the filter that causes the emptiness ...

Comment: This question can't be answered without code which will let us reproduce the problem. All we can do is guess, which is not very effective. Please provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), otherwise this question will probably be closed.

Comment: It sounds like the other part of your program is *very* important, in that it's what's providing the data which is not being read properly... if you go back to your original code, does that *still* work?

Comment: Which Java Persistence implementation are you using? OpenJPA?

Comment: EclipseLink(JPA 2.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you are using EclipseLink prior to 2.6 version and hit the [Bug#433075](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433075). This `devices` field is replaced with [`IndirectList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.0/org/eclipse/persistence/indirection/IndirectList.java/) (via reflection) which extends the `Vector` class and performs a lazy initialization. It was written for an older Java version which had no `stream()` method, so the `stream()` is actually called on uninitialized list returning an empty stream.

The bug is [fixed](http://git.eclipse.org/c/eclipselink/eclipselink.runtime.git/commit/?id=a364dc5a19dfc84966c7415342427741bbde51e8), thus you probably have to update the EclipseLink to 2.6 version. In EclipseLink 2.6 another class is [used when running on JDK 1.8](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.0/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/indirection/jdk8/IndirectList.java#29) which is stream-friendly.

Comment: Thanks!! But unfortunately it's still a bug in 2.6 when using @OrderColumn

Comment: @Swiss_Codeaholic, I see. It's a pity. You can call something like `devices.isEmpty()` to force the initialization, but I'd suggest not to use stream API till the next version will be released.

Comment: yes I gave it up now. Kind of sad that it's still not supported...I mean JDK8 is out for a while now. Anyway, thanks for your help @Tagir Valeev!

Comment: Thank you, I was using eclipselink v2.5.0 with this exact behavior, but with the version 2.6.0 the problem is gone