# Java Stream with JPA one to Many(LAZY) Relation not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-stream

> I have one Entity class called RCIEntity. which has a One to many mapping to its own type.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@OrderBy("name ASC")           
private List<RCIEntity> children; 

public final List<RCIEntity> getChildren() {
        return children;
}
```

so when i use this entity elsewhere with em.

```
rciEnitity.getChildren().stream().count() // always zero.
```

but if I create a sublist from it, then stream works fine.

```
List<RCIEntity> subList = get.getChildren().subList(0,get.getChildren().size());

long count1 = subList.stream().count();//works fine
```

Here is some code...

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<RCIEntity> q = cb.createQuery(RCIEntity.class);
        Root<RCIEntity> from = q.from(RCIEntity.class);

        CriteriaQuery<RCIEntity> select = q.select(from);
        q.select(from).where(cb.equal(from.get(RCIEntity_.project), true));

        List<RCIEntity> resultList = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();

        RCIEntity get = resultList.get(0);

        **long count = get.getChildren().stream().count(); // output 0. Doesn't work**

        System.out.println("First count"+count);
        List<RCIEntity> subList = get.getChildren().subList(0, get.getChildren().size());
        **long count1 = subList.stream().count(); // works fine output 4.**

         System.out.println("2nd count "+count1);
```

> **OUTPUT:  First count0,
>                2nd count 4  **

Comment: Are you using EclipseLink? Isn't it the same problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31941225/4856258)?

Comment: Yes seems its a bug of EclipsLink version 2.5.2. so i changed the version to 2.6.0 and its working fine. thanks for the answer. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433075

Answer (score 0):

So finally it was a bug of EclipseLink version 2.5.2. And Fixed in 2.6.0