# list.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); returns empty list

Tags: java, list, stream

choices is a List of two elements

but `choices.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());` returns an empty list

Would anyone know why?

```
//returns poll with list of choices
public Poll accessPoll(String pollId) {
        return pollRepository.findById(pollId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new IllegalStateException(String.format("No poll found for the ID: %s.", upperCasePollId)));
}
List<Choice> choices = pollManager.accessPoll(pollId).getChoices(); //returns list of choices
List<Choice> choices1 = pollManager.accessPoll(pollId).getChoices()
                .stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); //returns empty list
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: seems like `choices` is empty. Or are you using methods of the `Stream` like `filter` you haven't showed.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and include a [MRE].

Comment: @dan1st i edited the question to show ^^

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Turing85 I did ^

Comment: no, you did not...

Comment: @Turing85 how can I show proof then?

Comment: Provide a piece of valid code that reproduces the problem, i.e.  a [MRE], as text, not as image.

Comment: What is `result`? What does `getChoices()` return? Are you sure that is not empty?

Comment: @dan1st that's the intellij evaluator, just shows the result

Comment: yea 100% sure, i printed both out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look carefully at your screenshots. Your method `getChoices()` returns not a regular list but [IndirectList](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/indirection/IndirectList.html) which extends not a regular `Collection` but a `Vector` and that is why streams don't work as expected. This is [a known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433075) in EclipseLink,
you can read about it more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816650/java8-collections-sort-sometimes-does-not-sort-jpa-returned-lists/26841569#26841569) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939827/why-does-this-stream-return-no-element).

To overcome this behaviour, you can try to update your EclipseLink version up to 2.6.0, or you may try to wrap it with a new collection, like `new ArrayList<>()`